# Is lift force proportional to size?

Tags: aerodynamics, estimation, aircraft, lift

I'm trying to calculate lift force of a particular object I'm working with. However, I can't find much information on how much force is required for an object to stay in flight though.

My questions is, is lift force proportional to size?

Lets say we put a two planes in an earth like atmosphere. 
The first plane has these dimensions
length- 250 ft,
width- 63 ft, 
wingspan- 224 ft, 
lift coefficient- 1
velocity- 600 mph

2nd plane has these dimensions 
length- 100 ft,
width- 25 ft, 
wingspan- 89 ft, 
lift coefficient- 1 
velocity- 600 mph

Would these two theoretical planes have proportional lift force compared to each other. Or would the lift force of the 1st plane be much larger compared to its size than the smaller plane?

let me know if I need to change anything about this question.

Answer (score 2):

Given you have a lift coefficient, then lift force is proportional to area of the wing (which may not be proportional to the length of the airplane as a whole, or to the wingspan).

https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/airplane/lifteq.html

Answer (score 1):

To remain in flight, the lift force must always be equal to the aircraft's weight. this can be achieved with a wide variety of different combinations of wing area, airfoil shape, aspect ratio, available horsepower, trim state and airspeed.